# TYPO3 secure fileadmin direct links

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

In my TYPO3 Website I have lots of files under fileadmin/documents.

Problem is that all the documents are accessable if you know the direct link.

Is there a way to secure them and only access them when logged in as feuser?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is possible and there are extensions for that. For example:

- https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/secure_downloads
- https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/fal_securedownload

Comment: just with plain typo3 its not possible?

Comment: no, by default all files that are in the web directory of your server/hosting are accessible